# SSL Validation Failed during AWS SAM deploy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, serverless, aws-sam

I have created a Serverless project using one of the AWS SAM template.

I have builded the project using command `sam build`. When I tried to deploy the project using command `sam deploy --guided` I am getting this error:

```
Error: SSL validation failed for https://cloudformation.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)
```

**NOTE:** I have zscalar ON in my system. I have turned OFF it, and tried to deploy but still the same error.